# nodemailer node.js missing attachment or can't open

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I've started putting together a simple mailer with node.js and the nodemailer module. The mailer is working and I'm able to connect via SMTP transport on my server, but I'm having trouble pushing the attachment to the message.

I originally setup with well known service module with iCloud and the file was parsing just file, but when I switched to SMTP, I can't seem to get around it which is odd.

```
// Create a SMTP transport object
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
    host: 'mail.server.com',
    port: 25,
    secureConnection: false,
    auth: {
        user: 'user@server.com',
        pass: 'pass'
    },
    tls:{
        ciphers:'SSLv3'
    }
});

console.log('SMTP Configured');

var mailOptions;
// Message object
app.get('/send', function (req, res) {
    mailOptions = {
        from: 'user@server.com',
        to: req.query.toAddress,
        subject: req.query.messageSub,
        html: '<img src="cid:img@server" alt="" />,
        attachments: [
            {
                fileName: 'gif.gif',
                path: req.query.imageURL,
                cid: 'img@server'
            }
        ]
    };
    console.log('Sending Mail..');
    transport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Error occured');
            console.log(error.message);
            return;
        }
        console.log('Message sent successfully!');
        transport.close(); // close the connection pool
        res.redirect('/');
        return;
    });
});
```

I'm using the get method to get the fields from a form, logging it console, I see everything is parsed to the app.js file, but the attachment is either missing or contains an error , which makes me believe there's something wrong with the path, everything else gets sent ok.

The path I'm parsing (I tried manually putting it instead of req.query.imageURL as well) looks like this, but I tried other combinations:

```
'./public/including/christmas-gif.gif'
```

If I use a URL with http://... , I'm able to parse the file as well. I'll be glad for any tips.

Comment: If I use:

    host: 'mail.server.com',
    port: '25',
    secure: false,
    auth: {
        user: 'user@server.com',
        pass: 'pass'
    },
    tls:{
        ciphers:'SSLv3'
    },
    authMethod: 'PLAIN'

I get an error unable to verify the first certificate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this by setting up some extra options for the transport and updating the nodemailer from 0.7 to 1.0 with smtp-transport module like so...

```
// Create a SMTP transport object
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host: 'mail.server.com',
    port: '25',
    secure: false,
    ignoreTLS: true,
    auth: {
        user: 'user@server.com',
        pass: 'pass'
    },
    tls:{
        ciphers:'SSLv3',
        rejectUnauthorized: true
    },
    authMethod: 'PLAIN',
    debug: true
}));
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. You are sending the mail unencrypted

Comment: What adjustments would you suggest? This is very outdated and I hope this code is no longer in use... But it was a first try and I needed to make it work..